# Importing CSS from node_modules into a Create React App

Tags: webpack, sass, create-react-app, node-sass-chokidar

I've found loads of questions on this, but none of the answers are working..

I'm trying to import a font from node modules from this [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/roboto-fontface) into a Create React app

I've managed to get it compile with

```
@import './../node_modules/roboto-fontface/css/roboto/sass/roboto-fontface.scss';
```

however as soon as I run it I get

```
Module not found: You attempted to import ../../../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Black.eot
 which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of
src/ are not supported. You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to
it from project's node_modules/.
```

I've tried with ~, node_modules and various other ways of getting it into the project. Any clues?

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a assets/fonts/ directory inside src/ and put the fonts there :). Give it a try!